# Appending to numpy array within a loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I really hope to not have missed something, that had been clarified before, but I couldn't find something here.

The task seems easy, but I fail. I want to continuously append a numpy array to another one while in a for-loop:

```
step_n = 10
steps = np.empty([step_n,1])

for n in range(step_n):
    step = np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], size=(1,2))
    #steps.append(step) -> if would be lists, I would do it like that
    a = np.append(steps,step)
    #something will be checked after each n

print(a)
```

The output should be ofc of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` and look like:

```
[[-1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [-1. -1.]
 [ 1. -1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 0. -1.]
 [-1.  1.]
 [-1.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
```

However the code fails for some (most probably obvious) reasons. 
Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

step_n = 10
steps = np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], size=(1,2))
for n in range(step_n-1):
    step = np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], size=(1,2))
    print(steps)
    steps = np.append(steps, step, axis=0)
    #something will be checked after each n

print(steps)
```

One of the problems is that your *steps* variable that is initialized outside the for loop [has a different size](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) than each step inside. I changed how you initialized the variable *steps*, by creating your first step outside of the for loop. This way, your *steps* variable already has the matching size. But notice you need to reduce 1 iteration in the for loop because of this.

Also, you want to update the *steps* variable in each for loop, and not create a new variable "*a*" inside it. In your code, you would just end up with the *steps* array (that never changes) and only the last step.

Comment: Thanks a lot! At least creating "a" inside was stupid as hell.

Comment: @F. Trenk, how can I do this when generating data inside for-loop? For example, a = np.empty() for-loop  a=np.append(a, b)